# How do i handle attrs and listers in SaveInstanceState

Tags: android, onrestoreinstancestate

I'm building an android app but i get crashes when i rotate dialogs because i've not implemented the SaveInstanceState(). To save and restore simple objects like strings and primitives seems pritty straight forward. But I would also like to save some more complex objects like Context, AttributSet and some listeners? How do I handle that? To me they do not really seem to fit in a Bundle. Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
<activity
            android:name="yourActivityInwhichCallingDialog"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />
```

Comment: So this is in the manifest? And will it render the keyboard useless?

It worked! I'd love to know why. It was a lot easier then the OnSaveInstanceSate